# noscript image when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, noscript, image-fallback

I run my code through W3 validator.

And it's giving me this error:

"Element noscript not allowed as child of element picture in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)"

How can I improve the code to avoid the in the element?

```html
<picture>

    <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="(min-width: 600px)">
    <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN">

    {# When lazyloading, include noscript to still render image when JS is off #}
    {% if lazyload %}
      <noscript>
        <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN">
      </noscript>

</picture>
```

Comment: Try wrapping that bit in a `div` tag, see if it works.

Comment: The `<picture>` tag is already wrapped in a `<div>`.

Comment: I meant the `noscript` or `img` bit